# How to put html tags in <input value="xxx">

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a website for my internship and i'm facing some troubles.
I want to create a button with a special value. I'll link my code below so you'll be able to understand easier what i'm talking about :

```
<input type="button" class="newu" value="<i class='fa fa-pencil-square' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo $nom_prod['nom_produit'] ; ?>"/>
```

The problem is that quotes aren't working like i would like them to since i'm using xxx times simple and double quotes.
If you guys have any clue how i could manage to fix this it would be really nice to tell me how.

Thanks in advance & bybye.

Comment: You have put a tag as the value of the input and you cannot do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the *quotes aren't working like i would like them to*?

Comment: Well like Jay said, i want to put a tag + an echo in my input's value but i don't see how with only single and double quotes.
So if Jay is true and it's really impossible to do i'm trying something since this morning for nothing :(.

Comment: How about using a button `<button  class="newu">
<i class='fa fa-pencil-square' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo $nom_prod['nom_produit'] ;?>
</button>` I'll post it as the answer if it works for you. Cheers.

Comment: @IsabelInc Thank you so much it's actually working like i want :). Could you post that in answer so i validate yours ?
edit: oh didn't saw your edit, yeah you can post it as the answer thanks :)).

Comment: It should work according to this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-put-html-tags-in-input-box/2612 You need to replace the quotes with html entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a button element instead of an input.

```
<button class="newu"> <i class='fa fa-pencil-square' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo $nom_prod['nom_produit'] ;?> </button>
```

Good luck with your internship and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement you need to use  tag instead of using  tag. [Refer the difference here..](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

You can have almost anything between  tags.

And if you really want to go conventional way then you wrap your tag with other tags and set your values inside that using javascript.  But that's impracticable.